# How to create 2 many2one fields?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

My scenario is that I have a class `deg.form`. In this class there are two `many2one` fields named as `products` and `category` respectively. I am trying to create `many2one` relation of both these fields with other two fields present in the `product.product` class. The fields present in `product.product` are `name` and `asset_type`. I created the relation of the fields as :

```
 class deg_form(osv.osv):

      _name = "deg.form"
      _inherit="product.product"
      _columns = {
        'categ1':fields.many2one('product.category','Category'),
        'products':fields.many2one('product.product','Parent'), 
        'category':fields.many2one('product.product',string='Product'), 
        'product':fields.related('category','asset_type', type="many2one", relation ="product.product")    
        }
```

On doing this I get an error :

```
  Value Error: No such external ID currently defined in the system: product.product
```

I guess there might be any parameter that I'm missing here or its an inheritance issue. 
Plz guide me to fix this issue or point me where I'm wrong. Thanks

Regards

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your question right well. above you have 2 many2one fields as a relation to model product.product. if you want relation to fields of product.product (eg category or type) you have to use related fields instead of many2one or else.

Comment: Can't we use many2one instead of related because I tried related property but didnot work for me.

Comment: for related you need one many2one field and then you can use related fields for that many2one relation. example: 'product_id':fields.many2one('product.product', string="Product"),'product_type':fields.related('product_id','type',type="selection",string="Product Type")

Comment: I tried with : 'product_cat':fields.many2one('product.product',string='Product'), 
         'product':fields.related('product_cat','asset_type',type="selection",string='Product Type')  . And give xml view for 'product' . But in selection menu there are no values

Comment: can you please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: i dont know the field asset_type

Answer (score 0):

I was inheriting the id of `product.product` in my `xml` file . Therefore I removed it as it was not making sense to include it. It was like this:

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product"/>
```

Now the other field is bringing the values of the field `asset_type` which is defined in the `product.product`. Thanks all